# Equation in Table Too Large

Tags: tables, equations

I have a table where one of the formulas is simply too long. Is there a way to break up an equation in Latex in a table? It's already rotated and I tried p{5cm} but it simply overlaps the text as it can't find a place to break the equation, even with spaces added. Which packages might be useful? The one relevant answer on here that I found was frustratingly unhelpful.
Thanks in advance!

The code for my table:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} \hline
Objekt & Trägheitsmoment & Fehler Formel & Trägheitsmoment [$kg\cdot m^{2}$] \\ \hline
Hantelkörper &&& \\ \hline
Hohlzylinder & $J=\frac{m}{2}\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)^{2}$ & $\sqrt{\sigma_{m}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)\right)^{2} +\sigma_{r_{a}}^{2}\left(r_{a}m\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)\right)^{2} +\sigma_{r_{i}}^{2}\left(r_{i}m\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)\right)^{2}}$ & $0.00057668 \pm 0.00000000$ \\ \hline


\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two main options: first, use a substitution for common expressions. Second, make a `savebox` of a more complicated aligned equation, and insert that box into the table. This protects the `&` characters from being interpreted by the `tabular` environment.

Also, in terms of general table layout, see the [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) documentation. I've left your format intact, but if it were me, I'd get rid of most or all of the rules.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for aligned environment

\begin{document}

% Option 1: substiute single variable for common expression
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} \hline
Objekt & Trägheitsmoment & Fehler Formel & Trägheitsmoment [$kg\cdot m^{2}$] \\ \hline
Hantelkörper &&& \\ \hline
Hohlzylinder & $J=\frac{m}{2}R^{2}$ & $\sqrt{\sigma_{m}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}R\right)^{2} +\sigma_{r_{a}}^{2}\left(r_{a}mR\right)^{2} +\sigma_{r_{i}}^{2}\left(r_{i}mR\right)^{2}}$ & \\
&& $R=\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)$ & $0.00057668 \pm 0.00000000$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}

% Option 2: make a multi-line radical, but hide the & characters from the tabular with a savebox
\newsavebox\bigeqn
\begin{lrbox}{\bigeqn}
  \begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
$\sqrt{%
\begin{aligned}
   & \sigma_{m}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)\right)^{2} + \\
   & \sigma_{r_{a}}^{2}\left(r_{a}m\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)\right)^{2} + \\
   & \sigma_{r_{i}}^{2}\left(r_{i}m\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)\right)^{2}
\end{aligned}}
$
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} \hline
Objekt & Trägheitsmoment & Fehler Formel & Trägheitsmoment [$kg\cdot m^{2}$] \\ \hline
Hantelkörper &&& \\ \hline
Hohlzylinder & $J=\frac{m}{2}\left(r_{a}^{2}+r_{i}^{2}\right)^{2}$ & \usebox{\bigeqn} & $0.00057668 \pm 0.00000000$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about direct use of the content inside the minipage in the table. That is, without `\newsavebox` thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! Much better than my multi-row/overline mess I was trying

Comment: Pretty sure last time I used this method, someone else noted the savebox was unnecessary. Time for me to verify that and update my answer and other notes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The following is too long to post as a follow-up comment on Mike Renfro's answer. It should be clear, though, that my posting isn't so much a separate answer as an implementation of some of Mike's suggestions and observations.

Here, then, are some additional suggestions that will, hopefully, raise the visual and aesthetic appeal of the table:

- In tables, don't use vertical lines, get rid of most horizontal lines, and use the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to draw well-spaced versions of the remaining horizontal lines.
- Don't use `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately. Not only will you get occasional wild sizing mistakes if you try to leave the sizing job to TeX -- in Mike's posting, compare the parens in the first line of the radicand with those in the second and third lines; note also that the outer parens in the second and third lines are no larger than the inner parens, even though there's a clear typographic case for making the outer pair larger -- you'll also get undesirable spacing results. In the code below, I use `\bigl(` and `\bigr` only for the outer parens.
- To typeset scientific units according to SI standards, it's very convenient to use the `\si` macro of the `siunitx` package and type, say, `\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}`. Your input code will be much more readable, and the output is guaranteed to satisfy the standards on how scientific units should be typeset.
- Don't use a `center` environment *inside* a float unless you want to create lots of extra vertical whitespace. The macro `\centering` ought to be used in these situations.

Here's the resulting table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs} % various rule-drawing macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for \si macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "aligned" env. and \tfrac macro
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page margins to suit your needs

\begin{document}

% Modified form or Mike Renfro's Option 2: 
% Make a multi-line radical using an "aligned" environment, and hide the "&" characters 
% from "tabular" by placing the formula in a "minipage"

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{}} 
\toprule
Objekt & 
Trägheitsmoment & 
Fehler Formel & 
Trägheitsmoment [\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}] \\ 
\midrule
Hantelkörper \\ 
Hohlzylinder & 
$J=\frac{m}{2}(r_{a}^2+r_{i}^2{)}^2$ & 
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
$\sqrt{
\begin{aligned}
&\sigma_{m}^2\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}(r_{a}^2+r_{i}^2)\bigr)^2 \\
{}+{}&\sigma_{r_{a}}^2\bigl(r_{a}m(r_{a}^2+r_{i}^2)\bigr)^2 \\
{}+{}&\sigma_{r_{i}}^2\bigl(r_{i}m(r_{a}^2+r_{i}^2)\bigr)^2
\end{aligned}
}$
\end{minipage} & 
$0.00057668 \pm 0.00000000$ \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```